# socket.io : best way to find all sockets of a single user

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to make a push notification system, but to do that I need to find the proper way to emit something to ALL active sockets connections of a user (we suppose the logged-in User1 has opened my website in more than one tab of his web browser)

So, I was saving all active sockets-id in MySQL when a user was connected to his account (with sessions) :

```
user_id | socket_id
1       | 4lf3dsg2bx1u9d # User 1...
1       | 75ksdfzfff1u3d # ...has two active socket connections
2       | GEdsfoorbar1z4
```

and something like the following in my script :

```
io.sockets.sockets[socket_id].emit(...) # for each sockets of User1
```

But, I'm sure MySQL isn't the best way to sort sockets...

Does someone have a better solution ? Like a `io.sockets.has('user=1')` or something magic ?

**I also tested the solution to stock every sockets by user-id in an Object but what about performance ?**

Comment: "what about performance" ? what about it ? it can't get any faster than storing in RAM..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strategy of storing socket IDs isn't horrible, although storing them using something like [Redis](http://redis.io/) would be better than MySQL.  But for your case, you don't need to store the socket IDs at all: just use Socket.io's [rooms](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms) instead.  For example, every time User #1 establishes a socket connection, on the server do:

```
socket.join('user_1');
```

Then broadcast to everyone in the room (i.e. all the sockets that the user is connected with) using:

```
io.sockets.in('user_1').emit('event_name', data);
```

You can actually retrieve the IDs of all the sockets in a room, but the only time I really find it necessary is to count the number of IDs to see if the user is still connected.

Full docs for rooms are [on the Socket.io wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms).

Comment: Apparently users can be in multiple rooms (like User1 can be in "user_1" and "chatroom_1"), so this solution will not restrain my application. Thanks a lot !